# iOS 10 :launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] not getting called push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Im trying to make notifications compatible with `iOS10` but when i tap on notification in case of cold start the key is not getting called .
So i want to know if i need to implement another method to check if app is launched from cold start using push notification